Question about relatively prime polynomials in F[X]
Let $f$ and $g$ are two relatively prime polynomials in $F[X]$ $(F = R \text{ or } C)$ or equivalently $\gcd(f, g) = 1$. And let $p$ is any arbitrary polynomial in $F[X]$. I want to prove the following equality.
$\gcd(p, fg) = \gcd (pf, g) \cdot \gcd (f, pg)$
I am trying to prove that LHS and RHS divides each other and hence are equal as they are monic polynomials.
My attempt is as follows:
Let $\gcd(p, fg) = u$, $\gcd(pf, g) = v$ and $\gcd(f, pg) = w$.
Thus clearly $u$ is a common divisor of $p$ and $fg$, hence is a common divisor of $pf$ and $pg$.
Also since $v$ divides $g$ and $w$ divides $f$ therefore $vw$ divides $fg$. But I am unable to prove that $vw$ is a common divisor $p$ and $fg$ and hence $vw$ divides $u$. Also unable to show $u$ divides $vw$. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

How would you prove this fact for integers? Any issues faced when extending it to polynomials?

Thanks @CalvinLin for the response. I have found that vw divides u. Can you please give some hint why u divides vw.

My hint is to prove the fact for integers, and then extend that to polynomials. If you get stuck, write it out and explain why you're stuck.

Thank you once again @CalvinLin for the hint. Now I can prove this equality. Also  I understand that u divides vw for any three polynomials p , f and g. But vw divides u if and only if f and g are relatively prime polynomials.
